# Sage CRM - There is way to manage the session in my ASP page?

Tags: sage-crm

When session expires on a default Sage CRM page, it redirects you to a Log On again page, how can i achieve same behaviour in a custom .asp page?

I guessing that i can check whenever the session is expired or not and then redirect to `CRM/eware.dll/Do?SID=140762527052864&Act=523&Mode=1&CLk=T` or something like that, but how do i check if a session in Sage CRM is active or not?

Comment: Is the custom page embedded in CRM? If it is, Sage will automatically do this for you when the user's session expires.

Comment: Yes, right now it is a .asp page within a tab in the Company entity. When session expires it just show me this message "Not licensed or not registered correctly" in a blank page. I guessing that is due to the CRM being a demo license?